# Help with a solution about entropy!

Tags: entropy

I'm triying to solve this question [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235962/asymptotics-of-binomial-coefficients-and-the-entropy-function), but I don't understand why 
$$ -\log_2 (2\pi n pq)/(2n) $$ transforms into  $$O(\ln n/ n)$$
can you help me please :( !!

Answer (score 3):

Use that $\log ab=\log a+\log b$ and $\log_b a=\dfrac{\log a}{\log b}$. Here $\log$ is the natural logarithm. Remember you want to show there exists $C$ such that your expression in absolute value is $$\leq C\frac{\log n}n$$