# Lower bound on binomial coefficient

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, information-theory

I encountered the following claim

$$\frac{1}{n+1}2^{nH_2(k/n)} \le  \binom{n}{k} \le 2^{nH_2(k/n)}$$

where $H_2$ is the binary entropy function. The upper bound is rather well known but how does one show the lower bound?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235962/asymptotics-of-binomial-coefficients-and-the-entropy-function

Comment: Notice you can strengthen that to $\frac1{\sqrt{2n}}$ or even $\frac1{\sqrt{8k(1-k/n)}}$ by considering stirling approximations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower bound is a rewriting of $\int_0^1 x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \leq 2^{-nH_2(k/n)}$, which is estimation of the integral by (maximum value of function integrated, which occurs at $x=\frac{k}{n}$) x (length of interval).