# Find at least one solution or prove that it does not exist

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Please help me to find solution or prove that it does not exist.

$$
C^{2^k}_{2^n} < 2^{2^k (n - k)}, 1<k<n, k \in \mathbb{N}, n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

I tried to find solution numerically, but when $n$ > 20, the numbers grows very fast, so it seems like it has not solution (because I didn't find it when $n$ < 20). I am looking for analytical methods to prove this.

Comment: I take it that symbol on the left is $2^k$-factorial choose $2^n$-factorial? But if $n>k$, then this symbol evaluates to zero.

Comment: Wow. Never saw the notation used that way.

Comment: @gerry-myerson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation

Comment: @gerry-myerson You was right, it definitely my mistake, I fixed equation, so the left hand side must be $\frac{2^n!}{2^k!(2^n-2^k)!}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer.

Firstly we can introduce $N = 2^n$, $K = 2^k$. So the inequality will be rewritten as

$C_N^K < 2^{K(\log_2(N)-\log_2(K))}$

or

$\log_2(C_N^K) < K \log_2(N/K)$.

Secondly, according to [Best upper and lower bound for a binomial coeficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259907/best-upper-and-lower-bound-for-a-binomial-coeficient) we can use inequality

$C_N^K \ge (N / K)^K$.

It shows that there are no solutions.