# Binomial Coefficient bound using Entropy function

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove the following:

$${}^nC_k \geq \frac{1}{n+1}2^{nH(x)}$$

for $x = \frac{k}{n}$ and $ 0 \leq k \leq n$. The entropy function is the binary entropy function with $H(0) = H(1) = 0$.

I have already proved that $ {}^nC_k \leq 2^{nH(x)}$

I tried to use this along with the equation $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {}^nC_i x^i (1-x)^{n-i} = 1$

So this becomes $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {}^nC_i x^i (1-x)^{n-i} = 1 \le \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{nH(x)} x^i (1-x)^{n-i}$

So, $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{{}^nC_i}{ 2^{nH(\frac{m}{n})}} = 1 \le n+1$$

And then each individual term must be $\le n+1$, but this does not help. I am not sure how to approach this. I found a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423368/lower-bound-on-binomial-coefficient), but wasn't able to understand the answer.

Comment: See Example 11.1.3 of Cover & Thomas 2006.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer linked:

Note that $$\int_0^1 x^k (1 - x)^{n-k} \,dx = \frac{1}{(n+1)\binom{n}{k}},$$

either by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+x%5Ek+*(1+-+x)%5E(n+-+k)+dx) or induction via integration by parts.  If we note that the function $f(x) = x^k ( 1- x)^{n-k}$ achieves a maximum on $[0,1]$ at $x = \frac{k}{n}$, then we get the upper bound of $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \leq 1 \cdot f(k/n).$$

Noting that $$f(k/n) = \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^{n-k} = 2^{-n H_2(k/n)}$$ gives $$\frac{1}{(n+1)\binom{n}{k}} \leq 2^{-n H_2(k/n)}.$$

Rearranging terms completes it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do it with that summation in my question? I'm curious because I ran into this during self-study.