# Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log{\binom{n}{n_1}}}{n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-coefficients, factorial, entropy

We know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n_1}{n}=p$ and $0\leq p\leq 1$. Based on this information I want to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log{\binom{n}{n_1}}}{n}$. Any help?

Note: I want to show it is equal to $-p\log{p}-(1-p)\log{(1-p)}$ and I think calculating $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\binom{n}{n_1}$ is the main issue of the problem

Comment: Have you tried [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) ? Or are you purposely avoiding it ?

Comment: Stirling definitely works and is probably the best (and easiest) way to prove this.

Comment: Related (perhaps dup?) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235962/asymptotics-of-binomial-coefficients-and-the-entropy-function