# Proving that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{qk}\log_2\frac{\binom{qk}{k}}{q^{k-1}}=H(\frac{1}{q})-\frac{log_2q}{q}$

Tags: limits, logarithms, entropy

I need to prove the expression in the title where $H(\cdot)$ stands for the binary entropy function. First of all, a known property states that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log_2\binom{n}{pn}=H(p)$$ 
(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235962/asymptotics-of-binomial-coefficients-and-the-entropy-function)). Using that we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{qk}\log_2\frac{\binom{qk}{k}}{q^{k-1}}&=&\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{qk}(\log_2\binom{qk}{k}+log_2\frac{1}{q^{k-1}})\\
&=&\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{qk}\log_2\binom{qk}{k}+\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{qk}log_2\frac{1}{q^{k-1}}\\
&=&H(\frac{1}{q})+\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{qk}log_2\frac{1}{q^{k-1}}\\
&=&H(\frac{1}{q})+\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{qk}(log_2\frac{1}{q^k}-\log_2q)
\end{eqnarray*}

but I am out of ideas here.

Comment: It seems that you are almost done and if you compute the limit then you get the formula in the title.