# is the right approach to use the binary entropy function to get a $O(c^n)$ approximation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, binomial-coefficients

I just finished the implementation of an algorithm and wanted to report its approximate run-time in a O*($c^n$) format, the time analysis results is O*$n/2 \choose n/4$. I'm using the binary entropy function.

O*$n/2 \choose n/4$ $\approx$ O*($2^{\frac n 2 H(1/4)}$) $\approx$ O*($2^{\frac n 2 0.811}$) $\approx$ O*($1.324^n$)

Should I do this in a different way to do this accurately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) in the expression of the binomial O${n/2} \choose {n/4} $ for every factorial you come up with asymptotic complexity:
$$ \frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{n}} $$
This is not asymptotic to any expression of type $c^n$. This would anyway be a very good form for the reported asymptotic limit.

Indeed, if you use the fact proved in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235962/asymptotics-of-binomial-coefficients-and-the-entropy-function) (which I guess is what you used to get to your result), you obtain that 
$$ {n/2 \choose n/4 } \sim 2^{(H(1/2)^{2n})} $$
which is different from what you stated (you can't bring the exponent of $H$ down as exponent of $2$).