# estimation of mode of binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, estimation

I know the mode of a binomial $B(n,p)$ distribution is equal to $k =  \lfloor (n+1)p\rfloor$. I am wondering how to estimate the probability at this value, i.e. ${n\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$, like what's the order of this value in terms of $n$. Is it exp($-\Omega(n)$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mode behaves asymptotically like $np$.

You can use Stirling's approximation to show that
$$\binom{n}{np} \sim 2^{nH(p)} (2 \pi n p(1-p))^{-1/2}$$ where $H(p) := - p \log_2 p - (1-p) \log_2(1-p)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235962/asymptotics-of-binomial-coefficients-and-the-entropy-function)). So,
$$\binom{n}{np} p^{np} (1-p)^{n-np} \sim (2 \pi n p(1-p))^{-1/2} =\Theta(n^{-1/2}).$$

In the case $p=1/2$, the above yields the approximation $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}$, which is mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stirling%27s_approximation&oldid=1051145357#Estimating_central_effect_in_the_binomial_distribution) (there it is written as $\sqrt{2/\pi} \cdot 2^{-k}$ where $k = \log_4 n = \log_2 \sqrt{n}$).